# Where to find information about galvanic deposition of various metals?

Tags: electrochemistry

I am looking at the process to deposit Cu and Ag onto metallic surfaces using galvanic techniques. Unfortunately this works not as expected.

For example I use 2 rods of Cu in a bath of CuSO4 with some drops H2SO4. When applying a voltage, I get -- depending on the voltage -- either a block cover that can be wiped with a towel of a very rough Cu surface. I did not try with Ag/AgNO3 yet.

Anyway I have the problem, that I am looking for information or a form where I can post my problems and get useful tips, what I can do to enhance my baths.